# Compatibility browser in header page (hover) with firefox

Tags: php, javascript, css, firefox, browser

When I update Firefox to version 17, the submenu of my website no longer appears. When I installed an older version (like 15), the submenu works correctly.

The problem is like this website : http://www.terragon.net/

You must have version 17 or higher to see the problem with firefox. The problem occurs only with the 3 first menus; the others work correctly.

What's the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `table` when you have to `display` table data, NOT as mark-up.

Comment: I can see one 404 in your debugger console...I don't think that is the actual cause but you can try removing the error and running it again. http://www.terragon.net/blank.gif" (not found)

Comment: @bborisovs while that's generally good advice for someone trying to improve as a web developer, giving it to a person who has one specific problem with one specific browser, just because their problem happens to occur inside a table-based layout ... well it's kind of like telling someone whose arm is on fire that they shouldn't wear such flammable sunscreen ... the advice isn't exactly wrong, but it's not exactly helpful either.

Comment: @machineghost I agree on that one; I guess mine was more judgemental than helpful, my apologise. But if one believes one's approach is correct and in fact there are better solutions, I've been taught to encourage people to improve and use better methodology. Still, I appreciate your comment; note was taken! Apologise [at]Slim Mils.

Comment: :-) (and I'm glad that my awful analogy wasn't too confusing)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe your problem very well, but if you're referring to the menus stretching to fill the space, your problem seems to stem from the `width:auto` CSS property you have on your `.stctb` table.  If you set that width to a fixed amount (however many pixels wide you want your menus to be, plus the width of the left TD) it should solve that.